# Detox supports Apple TV simulator?

Tags: detox

Does Detox support Apple TV simulator? is yes, can you please provide configuration?

i tried below config but getting time out issue.

```
"appleTV": {
  "type": "ios.simulator",
  "binaryPath": "/Users/sudheerreddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TenFoot-dovkmoynmpydiwaergfenhdoccps/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/TenFoot-tvOS.app",
  "build": "cd .. && cd ten-foot && cd ios && xcodebuild -workspace TenFoot.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme TenFoot-tvOS -sdk appletvsimulator",
  "device": {
    "type": "Apple TV"
  },
  "name": "Apple TV"
```

Below is the output:

```
DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1603998688111 reportSpecs=true jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
detox[20401] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:52628...
detox[20401] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:52628
detox[20401] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=d820bc7a-1559-8038-cca0-a840c85e2dc9
detox[20401] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=d820bc7a-1559-8038-cca0-a840c85e2dc9
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byType "Apple TV"
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byId 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 --maxResults 1
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 com.*.*-dev
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #2] Uninstalling com.*.*-dev...
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] com.*.*-dev uninstalled
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 "/Users/sudheerreddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TenFoot-dovkmoynmpydiwaergfenhdoccps/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/TenFoot-tvOS.app"
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #3] Installing /Users/sudheerreddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TenFoot-dovkmoynmpydiwaergfenhdoccps/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/TenFoot-tvOS.app...
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] /Users/sudheerreddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TenFoot-dovkmoynmpydiwaergfenhdoccps/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/TenFoot-tvOS.app installed
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 com.*.*-dev
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #4] Terminating com.*.*-dev...
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4] com.*.*-dev terminated
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/sudheerreddy/Library/Detox/ios/5c0aa17e9008ad73710fb6d6131bf050c89aadad/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 com.*.*-dev --args -detoxServer "ws://localhost:52628" -detoxSessionId "d820bc7a-1559-8038-cca0-a840c85e2dc9" -detoxDisableHierarchyDump "true"
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #5] Launching com.*.*-dev...
detox[20401] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #6] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 com.*.*-dev
detox[20401] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] com.*.*-dev launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 9CCF99A4-E856-4426-8566-14E51175ECF4 log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == "TenFoot-tvOS"'
detox[20401] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=d820bc7a-1559-8038-cca0-a840c85e2dc9)
detox[20401] ERROR: Error: Exceeded timeout of 300000ms while handling jest-circus "setup" event
detox[20401] INFO:  Example is assigned to undefined
detox[20401] INFO:  Example: should show Home 
detox[20401] INFO:  Example: should show Home  [SKIPPED]

detox[20401] ERROR: DetoxRuntimeError: Aborted detox.init() execution, and now running detox.cleanup()

HINT: Most likely, your test runner is tearing down the suite due to the timeout error
detox[20401] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.

detox[20401] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=d820bc7a-1559-8038-cca0-a840c85e2dc9
detox[20401] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
detox[20400] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
MacBook-Pro-2:testing sudheerreddy$
```

Answer (score 0):

We haven’t tested on tvOS and we have no plans to support it for the time being.

That said, tvOS and iOS are quite close, so Detox probably supports tvOS just fine, and your problem lies elsewhere. Use our docs to investigate why your app times out.